# Assign and read session of user by PHPSESSID read from cookie

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

I want to authenticate chat user in my php app (through websockets). Now I am sending with chat message all cookies from domain. One of these cookies is session id. Is there any option to do something like this:

```
session_id($cookies['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user']['username'];
```

Or maybe is there any other method to authenticate user ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, with one small adjustment:

```
session_id($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']); //We use the `$_COOKIE` global array to access cookies
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user']['username'];
```

Be careful, though. Since you're using the same cookie as PHP ifself, this value is auto-generated unless of course you use `session_id($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);` before-hand. You'll need to make sure that an automatic session id is generated the first time the user visits your site.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't use $_COOKIE because ws protocol doesn't send cookies, so I must read cookies with javascript and send with message.

Comment: @MichałK.: Right, of course, my bad. Then perhaps just include it as `GET` parameter: `ws://website.com/path?sessID=` and appending the actual ID with JavaScript? Then you could (depending on the PHP framework you use) access it via `$_GET['sessID']`